# Extract name from facebook tag in facebook graph api

Tags: java, regex, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook graph api to display on my website the last facebook album of the corresponding facebook page.

However in the album description, when someone has been "tagged", you get in the JSON data something like

```
{...
  description : "this is the album desccription blabla the photograph is @[123456:123:PhotographerName] blabla..."
...}
```

Is there a way to get rig of the extra stuff? I would like either only the name or a usable HTML link.

Is there something possible with Facebook4j or with regexp??.

Thanks!

Edit : 
The wanted result is  :

```
{...
  description : "this is the album desccription blabla the photograph is PhotographerName blabla..."
...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match such a line with `^  description : ".+"$` and replace with nothing as long as the description does not hold any line breaks.

Based on your edit search for `@\[[\d:]+([A-Za-z]+)\]` or `@\[\d{6}:\d{3}:([A-Za-z]+)\]` (if the suggested structure is representative and should be matched as closely as possible) and replace with `\1`. (Might need to adjust depending on your specific application context.)

Comment: @Labe Added some detail based on your edit (which I didn't notice any earlier - sorry).